# How to read a bidimensional array inside a function?

Tags: c, arrays

i have this code how to read the bidimensional array using a function?
i write this function it works read all the numbers but when i output to console the array there are not the values that i entered

ex 
Input:
2 1 2 3 4 
Output:
16 256
1 4525376

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void citMat(int a, int n) {

    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
             printf("a[%d][%d]",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &a);
        }
}

int main()
{   int i,j;
    int a[10][10],n;
    printf("Introdu n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    citMat(a[10][10],n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read about sending arrays as parameters of function.

Comment: @Alex there are many mistakes in above program. Please restart learning C basics and avoid jumping directly to array.

Comment: Both type of indentations in one program. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the prototype to (Here array dimension is important)

```
void citMat(int a[10][10], int n)
```

Other changes are explained by others (The whole code is below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void citMat(int a[10][10], int n) {

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("a[%d][%d]:",i,j);
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
}
int main()
{   int i,j;
    int a[10][10],n;
    printf("Introdu n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n > 10)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input %d\n", n);
        return 1;
    }

    citMat(a,n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is very buggy. If the user enters any value that is different than 10 for the first scanf, the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: The purpose of the answer is to explain "how to pass 2D array to a function". However it is still good to point out other issues in code. I will edit the answer to fix invalid value read through scanf.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you want to pass a `2-d` array to function .*Change your function definition to* -

```
void citMat(int a[10][10], int n) {      // first parameter to take a 2-d int array
```

**2.** And then inside function `citMat` to take input-

```
 scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);    // you need to write like this
```

**Note** -

**1.** Array indexing starts from `0` , so if you have array `a[n]` then it have valid index from `0 to n-1` .

So start reading from `0` and till `n` in all `for` loops .  If you include `n` then you would access index out of bound and writing to it will cause *undefined behaviour*.

So, look out for that .

**2.** `int main()` **->** `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc,char **argv)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change few things in your program to make it work

1) Call the function with the base address of the array, lik

```
citMat(a,n);
```

---

2) Change your function definition to,

```
void citMat(int a[10][10], int n)
```

to make it accept 2D array as parameter.

---

3) Change the `scanf()` to read for each element,

```
scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
```

---

4) Since the array index starts from `0`, change all the `for` loops termination condition to

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
```

Comment: i get this compiler error "error: array type has incomplete element type|" for: `void citMat(int a[][],int n)`

Comment: The inner dimension in the array is missing, this will not compile.